# Does the order of a mysql multi-column MySQL index matter - if you're always using all columns in the query?

Tags: mysql, index

I'm aware that when you define a MySQL index that the order of the fields matters if the query is only using part of the index, as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252279/mysql-indices-and-order). But if your query is always going to use all columns defined in the index, then does index column order still not matter?

For example, consider a table with these columns:

- name
- gender
- age

Any my query of:

```
SELECT name WHERE gender='M' and age<18
```

Will there be a difference in performance if I define the index as (gender, age) vs (age, gender) ? Especially considering there will be one field with more unique values than the other.

I've read some tips on Percona's blog [here](http://www.percona.com/blog/2009/06/05/a-rule-of-thumb-for-choosing-column-order-in-indexes/) that indicate you should order your index columns on the most selective columns being first, but that's the only place I've heard that.

Anyone know? I'm using the innodb table type.

BONUS: Same question if your index is the primary key. Does it affect the answer?

Thanks so much for your input!

Comment: EXPLAIN is your friend: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-explain.html

Comment: I'm aware of explain, but was looking for generalized advice.

Comment: UPDATE: I found a good explanation that shows me that yes, it does matter - your most selective columns should be first: http://www.percona.com/blog/2009/06/05/a-rule-of-thumb-for-choosing-column-order-in-indexes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case it's a choice between bad and worse. `gender` is low selective (read MySQL has to read at least a half of index), if `age` comes first, `gender` part won't be used at all (because of `<` ). `(gender, age)` seems to be a bit better anyway.

Check with `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Handler%'` which index makes MySQL to read less rows.

```
mysql> FLUSH STATUS;
mysql> SELECT name WHERE gender='M' and age<18;
mysql> mysql> show status like 'Handler%';
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Handler_commit             | 38    |
| Handler_delete             | 8     |
| Handler_discover           | 0     |
| Handler_external_lock      | 154   |
| Handler_mrr_init           | 0     |
| Handler_prepare            | 0     |
| Handler_read_first         | 35    |
| Handler_read_key           | 62    |
| Handler_read_last          | 0     |
| Handler_read_next          | 153   |
| Handler_read_prev          | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd           | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 5947  |
| Handler_rollback           | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint          | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0     |
| Handler_update             | 1     |
| Handler_write              | 617   |
+----------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: So you're saying yes, that it does matter and most selective should be first? BTW the age/gender is just a hypothetical example of fields with differing cardinality.

Comment: yes. the goal of indexes is to read as little as possible from table, yet to satisfy the query.
if high selective field comes first then MySQL will read less rows.

Comment: Got it - thanks. Not sure why I can't find that in the mysql docs anywhere, unless it's just common sense ;-)